# Click function executed on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I am trying to bind my html button to a function using knockout. The function is only supposed to pop up the alert message when the button is clicked but instead, the function is executed on page load.

Here's my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='knockout-2.2.0.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='studentapp.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="new_student">
      <input type="text" class="name" placeholder="name" data-bind="value: person_name, hasfocus: person_name_focus()">
      <input type="text" class="age" placeholder="age" data-bind="value: person_age">

      <button data-bind="click: createPerson">Create</button>        
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my js:

```
function createPerson(){
  alert("Name ");
};

ko.applyBindings(new createPerson());
```

The console is displaying the following:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of null

Any ideas ?

Comment: What is `ko` ? Can you post that part of the JS ?

Comment: Can't you use just the onclick trigger?

Comment: Refer to this [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/clickCounter.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look on this [tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/)

Your code should looks like

```
var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.name = "Name";
    self.age = 22;
    self.buttonClicked = function () {
        alert(self.name + " is " + self.age + " old");
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Here is working fiddle [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/3hs7zwr6/3/).

EDIT:
Fiddle was fixed, and link updated

Comment: I looked at you fiddle sample, I clicked the button but nothing is happening.

Comment: it works. Can you please tell me why you had to nest a function inside a function to get it to work? Why would it not work they way I had it ? I don't want to just copy paste your code and get done with it. I want to understand what you did.

Comment: You used createPerson for your ViewModel. The ViewModel is supposed to wrap all your observables and Knockout-accessible functions.
The click binding takes a function. If you give it code to evaluate, you might expect Knockout to wrap it in a function, but it doesn't, it just evaluates it, hoping to get a function back.

Answer (score 2):

view model should look like this

```
var createPerson = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.name = "Mike";
    self.sendAlert = function(){
        alert(self.name);
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new createPerson());
```

then your button can use

```
<button type="button" data-bind="click:sendAlert"></button>
```

Comment: In general this is a good comment about how view models work, but given the error OP is getting I think his immediate problem is calling applyBindings to early, which is not remedied by your suggestion. (A good tip nonetheless though.)

Answer (score 0):

try put defer tag in your script, and put all javascript code after `</html>` tag, it`s a good practice.

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src='studentapp.js' defer="defer"></script>
```